# How to reference a value in fxml file of Java FX?

Tags: javafx, fxml

Like in android i would use for example `width ="@dimen/bottom_padding"`
How can i do something similar in Java FXML files?

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html